# TabHost Button Sizing Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tabhost

I am using a TabHost to hold 3 fragments and have created a method that sets the Tab selected/unselected background colors. The background colors are drawn using a drawable xml file. The problem that I am getting is when a tab is selected, the width is adjusted for the actual tab buttons. They need to stay the same size no matter what. How would this be fixed?

[image: Tab buttons showing the sizing error]

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
private void setSelectedTabColor() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    int textSize = 22;

    int current = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        txt.setTextSize(textSize);
        txt.setTypeface(font);
        txt.setLayoutParams(rllp);
        txt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        if (i == current) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1_active);
        } else {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

button_type1.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape>

                <!-- Gradient Bg for Button -->
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/button_type1_pushed" android:startColor="@color/button_type1_pushed" />

                <stroke android:width="0.05dp" android:color="@color/button_type1_border" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<item android:state_enabled="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@color/button_type1_normal" android:startColor="@color/button_type1_normal" />

                <stroke android:width="0.05dp" android:color="@color/button_type1_border" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

button_type1_active.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape>

                <!-- Gradient Bg for Button -->
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="@color/button_type1_pushed" android:startColor="@color/button_type1_pushed" />

                <stroke android:width="0.05dp" android:color="@color/button_type1_border" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
<item android:state_enabled="true"><layer-list>
        <item><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="@color/button_type1_active" android:startColor="@color/button_type1_active" />

                <stroke android:width="0.05dp" android:color="@color/button_type1_border" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code that was used to fix the problem. Setting the padding for the parent View to 0 was necessary:

```
private void setSelectedTabColor() {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rllp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    rllp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    int textSize = 22;
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

    View currentView;
    int current = mTabHost.getCurrentTab();
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                .findViewById(android.R.id.title);
        txt.setTextSize(textSize);
        txt.setTypeface(font);
        txt.setLayoutParams(rllp);
        txt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
        currentView = mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams currentLayout = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) currentView
                .getLayoutParams();
        currentLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        currentView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        currentView.setLayoutParams(currentLayout);
        currentView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        if (i == current) {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1_active);
            txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1_active);
        } else {
            mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i)
                    .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1);
            txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_type1);
            txt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if(i==0||i==1){
            txt.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

The same way you set the `height`, you may set the `width` to the maximal width of the current layout. Something like this should work:

```
final Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
final Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();

mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = (int) params.width * 0.9;
```

I think setting `width` to `MATCH_PARENT` instead of `WRAP_CONTENT` should work too.